# Length of a formula in propositional logic without negation

Tags: logic

I shall proof that for every propositional formula without negations and $n$ binary connectives, we have $L(F)=4n+1$, where $L$ is the Length of the formula.

I wanted to use structural induction, starting with showing that for any atom, the equation holds.

$L(A) = 4*0 + 1 = 1$

then my approach was to use any two propositional formulas and connect them with any binary connective $\lor, \land, \rightarrow \iff$, denoted by $\circ$
This gives me:

$L(F \circ G) = L(F) + L(G) + 3$

since we add $1$ connective and $2$ brackets. Then I am kind of stuck. I could say that per hypothesis we have $L(F) = 4n+1$ and $L(G) = 4m+1$, thus $L(F \circ G) = L(F) + L(G) + 3 = 4n + 1 + 4m + 1 + 3$. But this did not lead to anything.

I appreciate any hints!

Comment: $(4n+1)+(4m+1)+3= 4(n+m)+(3+1)+1= 4(n+m+1)+1$.

Comment: Actually I had that written on paper as well, but I had no idea if this is enough for a proof. How would one finish this proof? $n+m+1$ is the extra connective, and thus the formula holds for any $L \circ G$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is enough: the result is of "form" $4k+1$.